# NLB configuration

Tags: nlb

I have an NLB configured for two web servers. The NLB is a software NLB configured on Windows Server 2008 R2. The web servers are IIS servers. For a request of 5000 users, all my requests are going to one web server. So when does NLB send requests to other server. Also how do I configure NLB for sticky sessions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLB will distribute the load according to the chosen filtering mode & affinity settings for your NLB cluster. If you've set "Single" filtering mode, all traffic will go to a single server. If you've selected "Multiple host", the affinity decides which host will receive the traffic of recurring users. If you've chosen Single/Class C affinity, all users from the same IP / IP class C range will hit the same server (beware proxies & internal network topologies in this case).

Furthermore, even in multiple host mode, you can choose a distribution factor under the port rules so one server may be at 100% while the other is at 0%.

I've got a short video on my blog on how to setup a simple NLB cluster that shows the filtering mode & affinity settings:
http://improve.dk/blog/2008/03/08/using-network-load-balancing-for-availability-and-scalability

Answer (score 0):

Where do the requests come from?

NLB usually balances requests based on the client IP address (although this can be configured), so, if f.e. you're stress-testing it from a single machine, or if you have a reverse proxy which doesn't pass on the original caller IP, your requests will always be handled by a single server.

Answer (score 0):

Comments from Mark S. Rasmussen helped in configuring NLB properly. Now how showuld we configure sticky session on NLB?